# Append values to a data frame from another data frame, given a condition and improving efficiency of the code in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataset called `train`, to which I want to append the values in the columns of `total`, when the attributes `created_at` and `user_id` match in both the datasets.
The following is the code I have written.

```
total = read.csv('Data.csv')
train = read.csv('train.csv', sep='\t')

train$lang=NA
train$tweet_lang=NA
train$time_zone=NA
train$instrumentalness=NA
train$liveness=NA

for (i in 1:nrow(train))
{
    train[i,'lang'] = total[which( total$created_at == as.character(train[i,'created_at']) && total$user_id == as.character(train[i,'user_id']) ),'lang']
    train[i,'tweet_lang'] = total[which( total$created_at == as.character(train[i,'created_at'])&& total$user_id == as.character(train[i,'user_id']) ),'tweet_lang']
    train[i,'time_zone'] = total[which( total$created_at == as.character(train[i,'created_at'])&& total$user_id == as.character(train[i,'user_id']) ),'time_zone']
    train[i,'instrumentalness'] = total[which( total$created_at == as.character(train[i,'created_at'])&& total$user_id == as.character(train[i,'user_id']) ),'instrumentalness']
    train[i,'liveness'] = total[which( total$created_at == as.character(train[i,'created_at'])&& total$user_id == as.character(train[i,'user_id']) ),'liveness']
    }
```

However, for `i=3`, I get the error: `Error in x[...] <- m : replacement has length zero`. How can I populate the value in the dataset `train` even if it is an empty string? 
Also, this implementation (using loops) is very slow. Is there any way to vectorize or parallelize the code to make it run faster?

Comment: what about `indexes <- which( total$created_at == as.character(train[i,'created_at'])&& total$user_id == as.character(train[i,'user_id']) )` and then  `train <- total[indexes, ]` instead of loop

Comment: This code isn't reproducible as we don't have access to your `Data.csv` or `train.csv`. Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcvec) on what you should provide in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a left join, as implemented, e.g. in the dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
    a = 1:4
    , b = letters[1:4]
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    a = 1:3
    , c = LETTERS[1:3]
)

df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = "a")
```

This leads to

```
  a b    c
1 1 a    A
2 2 b    B
3 3 c    C
4 4 d <NA>
```

The %>% is called a pipe-operator. You can learn more about the dplyr package in the book 'R for Data Science' which you can also find online [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/).

Comment: Oh, if you don't know what left join is, search for SQL join on youtube or google. It's basically "add what's on the right [df2] to what's on the left [df1] if the key [by] exists on the left."

Comment: Thanks. I do have an idea of what left join is. What if I want to merge the dataset based on two columns which are common to both the data frames?

Comment: I figured it out. by=c('column1', 'column2') did the trick. Thanks again.